# Creating sparse matrix in MEX

Tags: c, matlab, sparse-matrix, mex

How to create a 2d sparse matrix in a MEX-file written in C. After creating the matrix how to access the elements individually like in C , say `mat[i][j]`?

I tired using [`mxCreateNumericArray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreatenumericarray.html) function but I wasn't able to access the elements and also make it as a sparse matrix.

Please help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[See this page on mxCreateSparse.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreatesparse.html)  Then you'll want to look at [mxSetPr](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxsetpr.html), [mxSetIr](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxsetir.html) and [mxSetJc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxsetjc.html) and the corresponding "get" versions.

[Here's an example of how to allocate a sparse matrix.](http://web.archive.org/web/20060211061327/http://amath.colorado.edu/computing/Matlab/OldTechDocs/apiref/mxcreatesparse.html)  I realize this is an old link, but to the best of my knowledge, it hasn't changed.

Basically, [how it works](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/matlab-data.html#f47606) is that the `ir` data contains the row indices.  The `jr` data contains a list of indices into the `ir` array.  For instance, in the link on how to allocate a sparse matrix, the code:

```
...
static double  static_pr_data[NZMAX] = {5.8, 6.2, 5.9, 6.1};
static int     static_ir_data[NZMAX] = {0, 2, 1, 3};
static int     static_jc_data[COLS+1] = {0, 2, 4};
...
```

the array `static_jc_data` tells you that indices `static_jc_data[c]` through `static_jc_data[c+1]-1` of `static_pr_data` and `static_ir_data` correspond to the column `c` of the matrix.  Within that range (`static_jc_data[c]` to `static_jc_data[c+1]-1`) the entries of `static_pr_data` gives you the values in the matrix and `static_ir_data` gives you the correct rows.

For example, the matrix here would be:

```
A = [ 5.8  0
      0    5.9
      6.2  0
      0    6.1];
```

To answer your questions about how to access elements individually, you have to search for whether the `i,j`th element exists and if it does return it, otherwise return 0.  To do this, you'd search from `static_ir_data[static_jc_data[j]]` through `static_ir_data[static_jc_data[j+1]-1]` to see whether your `i` exists.  If it does, then the corresponding entry in `static_pr_data` will contain your entry.  If it doesn't, then return 0.

However, typically with sparse matrix usage, if you're doing a lot of searching through the matrix to see if a certain element exists, you may want to think about how you're using it.  Typically, it's much better to perform whatever operation you're doing by only going through the non-zero elements once instead of searching for each `i,j`th entry.

Oh, and one last thing.  Keep in mind that in the MEX code, all your indices are 0 based, but they are 1 based in MATLAB.  That should add to the fun.

Comment: I understood ur example , but how do i create the jc array, i dint understand that part..the thing is i have to make a 2d matrix in which i fill in the values at some locations through some calculation..say w[1][2]= some formula .. Now do i have to create a prdata array which contains all the non zero elements?

Comment: Jc array is one more than the number of columns. It's the cumulative sum of the number of nonzero elements in the columns thus far. This allows one efficiently determine the number of elements in a given column.

Comment: @pxu - if you think about it carefully, this is exactly consistent with what I said.

Comment: It is. Just trying to give a one liner to address rohit's question. I personally dislike playing with Matlab sparse matrices in mex. If you are concerned about performance, use a library like CSparse and std::map to sort the keys.

Comment: @rohit, yes, see pxu's comment for how to create the jc array.  To give you a hint, element jc[0] will always be 0, and element jc[c+1] will tell you the cumulative number of elements seen thus far (in all columns up to and including column `c` (assuming `c` is 0-based)

Comment: +1 Nice writeup on sparse matrices in MEX. I wish I could upvote more than once...