# how to pass sparse matrix to shared library from MATLAB

Tags: c, matlab, sparse-matrix, mex

I want to pass a sparse matrix to a shared library from MATLAB, do some operation there (written in C), and then return it.

I can pass a dense matrix and use, pretty easy. But, I have no idea how to pass a sparse matrix to a shared library from MATLAB. What I've found are all concerned about MEX.

It is appreciated if give some information about sparse matrix format in MATLAB and the conversion in C.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/6095548/1499402

Answer (score 2):

Internally MATLAB stores sparse matrices using [Compressed sparse column](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_column_.28CSC_or_CCS.29) (CSC) format. Once you understand the format, you could then pass a sparse matrix to external code by getting the arrays `pr`, `pi`, `ir`, and `jc` (using the MEX-functions [mxGetPr](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetpr.html), [mxGetPi](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetpi.html), [mxGetIr](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetir.html), [mxGetJc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetjc.html) respectively).

- `pr` (and `pi` if the matrix is complex) is a double-precision array of length `nzmax` containing the nonzero values of the matrix.
- `ir` points to an integer array also of length `nzmax` containing the row indices of the corresponding elements in `pr` and `pi`.
- `jc` points to an integer array of length `n+1`, where `n` is the number of columns in the sparse matrix. The `jc` array contains column index information. If the `j`-th column of the sparse matrix has any nonzero elements, `jc[j]` is the index in `ir` and `pr` (and `pi` if it exists) of the first nonzero element in the `j`-th column, and `jc[j+1] - 1` is the index of the last nonzero element in that column. For the `j`-th column of the sparse matrix, `jc[j]` is the total number of nonzero elements in all preceding columns. The last element of the `jc` array, `jc[n]`, is equal to `nnz`, the number of nonzero elements in the entire sparse matrix.