# N-dimensional indexing allowed for Full matrices only. - issue using sparse command MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I would like to store an array of different sparse matrices into a single matrix, something like this:

```
A(:,:,1) = sparse([0 0 1; 0 1 0]);

A(:,:,2) = sparse([0 0 1; 0 0 0]);

A(:,:,3) = sparse([1 0 1; 0 0 0]);

A(:,:,4) = sparse([0 0 1; 0 1 0]);
```

But, I get the error:

**N-dimensional indexing allowed for Full matrices only.**

It seems like others have ran into this problem:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/276098

but the link to the "bug fix" was broken and I am not sure how to deal with this issue. I know that I could use cell arrays but I know that they are slow and I am trying to avoid them. I guess that I could also use the full() command, but I am not sure if that is the best (fastest) way.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you need sparse matricies? In general they are slower then normal matricies, but sometimes unavoidable due to memory constraints.

Comment: btw that link is irrelevant anyway, here is a cached copy: http://web.archive.org/web/20100308064805/http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/rn/bsdgysw-1.html#bseheyh-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, you cannot create N-dimensional sparse arrays in MATLAB, they have to be 2D matrices.

In addition, the types supported are either `double` or `logical` only (although there are [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20561443/97160) to create `single` sparse matrices, but they are ultimately useless for any actual use).

If you want to store multiples sparse matrices, you gotta use a container type (like cell-arrays or structs).

---

*Rant*: Claiming that cell-arrays are slow is ill-founded. It doesn't matter much if you were looping over `arr(:,:,i)` or `arr{i}`, unless the goal was to perform vectorized operation on the whole ND-array in the first place (not supported for sparse arrays). So just think of a cell array as an array of pointers, and `arr{i}` is simply de-referencing the pointer to get to another array...